# Internet site collection Office 365

Tags: office-365, internet-sites

I believe I used to create trial tenancy in Office 365, and I had the option to create internet site in my tenancy, now I have the option to create only private site collection, the link to create public site is hidden. anyone facing the same issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting January 2015, Microsoft is making changes to the SharePoint Online Public Website feature and have discontinued it

> As part of the evolution of the Office 365 service, we periodically evaluate the capabilities of the service to make sure that we’re delivering the utmost value to customers. After careful consideration, we concluded that for public websites, Office 365 customers would be better served by third-party providers whose core competency is public websites. Therefore, we’ve made the difficult decision to discontinue the SharePoint Online Public Website feature so that we can focus our efforts and investments on delivering capabilities in Office 365 that will bring more value to our customers.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3027254